# Springer spaniel short term lameness after high intensity workout

Tags: dogs, injury

I have a 8 month old working line  springer spaniel bitch.

Recently I have noticed that while playing fetch she seems to suddenly become totally lame in the same back leg for about 2 or 3 minutes, then appears to walk it off and be fine again.

I originally thought just a pulled muscle or cramp from sprinting after the ball and turning quickly to jump/fall and grab it. However it keeps happening to the same leg which makes me think maybe it's something more?

Has anyone had any experience of this or advice?

Obviously you hear horror stories of early arthritis or hip dysplasia (her parents have good hd scores though) but I'm thinking maybe something like panosteitis given her age? I also think she might be about to get her first season, not sure if that's got any relevance but including in case.

Thanks